# Uniform and pointwise convergence of sequence of function of $f_n(x) = [\log(1+x)]^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

I need to study the pointwise convergence of

$f_n(x) = [\log(1+x)]^n$

for every $x$ of the domain of the functions.

After i have to prove that the sequence of functions $f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent to $f$ on the interval $[\frac{1}{2},1]$.

I've shown that in $(-1,\infty)$

$$dom(f_n(x))=\{x:x>-1\}$$

so for $x=0$ $f_n(x)=0  \xrightarrow{} 0$  for n $\rightarrow$ + $\infty$

It remains to show what happen for  $x\neq 0$ but i don't find the pointwise convergence.
How can i proceed?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@andrew 
The pointwise limit is clearly $0$ for $x\in(-1+e^{-1},e-1)$. On $[1/2,1]$ you have
$$
|\log(x+1)^n-0|=|\log(1+x)|^n<(\log 2)^n\to 0
$$
and this establishes the uniform convergence to zero.

Comment: how do you understand that the pointwise limit is $0$ for $x \in (-1+e^{-1},e-1)$?

Comment: Only for those values you have $\log(1+x)$ is in $(-1,1)$ and increasing powers approach zero. If $x=-1+e^{-1}$ your sequence is $(-1)^n$ which has no limit. If $x=e-1$ it is constant equal to 1, so the limit is $1$ there. Outside the given interval your sequence is $A^n$ with $A\notin[-1,1]$ and is thus has no limit if $A<1$ and the limit is $+\infty$ if $A>1$.

Comment: thank you very much @GReyes

Comment: Your first sentence should have an iff.